# pyPandas: mess with join/append/concat two dataframes

Tags: python, join, dataframe, pandas, concatenation

I have two dataframes: one with 12 cols and the other with 9, both of them have 624 rows. I would like to join them side by side resulting in a 21 cols dataframe with the same 624 number of rows. I want to preserve the rows order. Observe that both dataframes are aligned in descending order of the column 'Name' and the column 'L1'. I have tried several things to join them by axis=1 ignoring index or not. All that I have is a dataframe with rows doubled and a bunch of NANs. I also tried to concat and append, but with no success.
Any help is appreciated.

```
n        Name  Position  ObsHET  PredHET  HWpval  %Geno  FamTrio  MendErr    MAF Alleles Rating
48  rs17818182  32945574   0.153    0.141  1.0000   98.9       29        0  0.076     G:T    NaN
45  rs17818176  32944041   0.033    0.033  1.0000  100.0       30        0  0.017     G:T    NaN
133  rs17818104  32879319   0.136    0.126  1.0000   98.9       29        0  0.068     T:C    NaN
105  rs17818087  32863970   0.241    0.307  0.2037   96.7       29        1  0.190     T:C    NaN
165  rs17818021  32794604   0.302    0.329  0.7637   85.6       20        0  0.208     A:C    NaN

           L1        L2      D   LOD     r2  CIlow  CIhi   Dist T-int
31331  rs17818182  rs640249  0.423  0.27  0.012   0.04  0.80  66596     -
31328  rs17818176  rs640249  1.000  0.21  0.014   0.05  0.97  65063     -
29083  rs17818104  rs640249  1.000  3.01  0.092   0.51  1.00    341     -
27571  rs17818087  rs640249  0.143  0.14  0.006   0.01  0.44  15008     -
14857  rs17818021  rs640249  0.311  0.68  0.033   0.06  0.57  84374     -
```

Answer (score 0):

One alternative is to merge on 'Name' and 'L1':

```
In [36]: df
Out[36]: 
   a         b         c
0  k -0.787279  1.431643
1  m  1.278970  2.294351
2  n  0.793787 -2.337330

In [37]: df2
Out[37]: 
   x         y         z
2  k -2.419514  1.178166
3  m -0.827535 -0.113485
4  n  0.135814 -0.612922

In [38]: df.merge(df2, left_on='a', right_on='x')
Out[38]: 
   a         b         c  x         y         z
0  k -0.787279  1.431643  k -2.419514  1.178166
1  m  1.278970  2.294351  m -0.827535 -0.113485
2  n  0.793787 -2.337330  n  0.135814 -0.612922
```

Another is to call DataFrame.reset_index first before you call merge:

```
In [50]: df.reset_index().merge(df2.reset_index(), left_index=True, right_index=True)
Out[50]: 
   index_x  a         b         c  index_y  x         y         z
0        0  k -0.787279  1.431643        2  k -2.419514  1.178166
1        1  m  1.278970  2.294351        3  m -0.827535 -0.113485
2        2  n  0.793787 -2.337330        4  n  0.135814 -0.612922
```

Comment: Thanks for helping. I had realized that reset would work, however, why to reset index to concat dfs ignoring them?

Comment: might be slightly confusing naming, but `ignore_index` ignores the concatenation axis, not `df.index`.

Comment: I don't think so. At least in `concat`, you have to declare axis.

Comment: what's ignored is determined by the axis parameter